# Setting Docker Variables

Tags: docker

I am trying to obtain set some environment variables in a Docker container.

The following works fine

```
ENV CORE_SQL_URL "jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/db"
ENV JAVA_OPTS -DCORE_SQL_URL=${CORE_SQL_URL}
```

however,  if I I want to overide CORE_SQL_URL how can I force JAVA_OPTS to be updated.

running the container with docker run  -e "CORE_SQL_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/db2" results in the following

```
JAVA_OPTS=-DCORE_SQL_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/db
CORE_SQL_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/db2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just setting the JAVA_OPTS in the shell script called by my ENTRYPOINT before launching my java app.

Answer (score 5):

The `ENV` command in a Dockerfile is executed at build time, while the `-e` flag to `docker run` is, of course, a run time parameter. There's no way for the build-time parameter to do anything with run time parameters you're passing in so you'll have to pass in both environment variables to get the desired result.